# iphone - is the hotspot isolated (can you see other devices)?

Tags: iphone, chromecast

When I turn on the Apple hotspot feature, is it an isolated network, or can I see other devices on it?

Can I use it to connect a third device to a Chromecast?

As in tablet -> iPhone with hotspot (and cellular data off) -> Chromecast?

I want to use a Chromecast while on holiday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personal Hotspot is designed for sharing a cellular data connection, not for acting as a wireless access point or router. This means that multiple devices connected to the same iOS device cannot connect to one another - they can only access the Internet (assuming the cellular data connection is active). Unfortunately I can't find any Apple documentation to confirm this, but have seent his from personal experience.

Your best solution is to purchase a portable wireless access point and connect all of your devices to that.

Hootoo makes a dependable and well supported line of travel routers starting at $20. Models get better features and even built in batteries for another $10 and $20 respectively.

- [https://www.amazon.com/HooToo-Wireless-Performance-TripMate-Hotspot/dp/B00HZWOQZ6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HZWOQZ6)

Comment: -1 because in *my* personal experience, devices can communicate with each other on the hotspot LAN. This functionality may be limited, but it does work at least on some iOS devices.

Comment: @sjy can you share more details about ports / protocols that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Devices can see each other when connected on an iPhone 13, software version 15.1.1. I can login from my Mac to a connected Raspberry Pi via `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` while both are connected to the phone's hotspot.